# SIGSEGV when writing java code

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-2.2-froyo

I have a piece of code which runs quite happily on the HTC Desire HD [v2.3.3], but when running on an HTC Desire [v2.2] crashes with a SIGSEGV when closing a bluetooth socket:

```
07-25 16:23:52.462: INFO/DEBUG(64): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
07-25 16:23:52.462: INFO/DEBUG(64): Build fingerprint: 'vodafone_uk/htc_bravo/bravo/bravo:2.2/FRF91/284385:user/release-keys'
07-25 16:23:52.462: INFO/DEBUG(64): pid: 2494, tid: 2512  >>> uk.co.etiltd.bluetooth <<<
07-25 16:23:52.462: INFO/DEBUG(64): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), fault addr deadbaad
07-25 16:23:52.462: INFO/DEBUG(64):  r0 00000000  r1 afd14699  r2 00000027  r3 00000074
07-25 16:23:52.467: INFO/DEBUG(64):  r4 afd42328  r5 00000000  r6 00000000  r7 0000a000
07-25 16:23:52.467: INFO/DEBUG(64):  r8 484ffb08  r9 432a4e38  10 808a3448  fp 432a4e34
07-25 16:23:52.467: INFO/DEBUG(64):  ip 00001730  sp 484ffa88  lr deadbaad  pc afd11cf0  cpsr 60000030
07-25 16:23:52.467: INFO/DEBUG(64):  d0  6472656767756265  d1  6465736f6c632039
07-25 16:23:52.467: INFO/DEBUG(64):  d2  6e72757465722033  d3  6c6f6f70206f7439
07-25 16:23:52.467: INFO/DEBUG(64):  d4  41876f9c41876f68  d5  41aad25041876fd0
07-25 16:23:52.467: INFO/DEBUG(64):  d6  41aad2b841aad000  d7  41aad32041aad2ec
07-25 16:23:52.467: INFO/DEBUG(64):  d8  0000000000000000  d9  43e0000000000000
07-25 16:23:52.467: INFO/DEBUG(64):  d10 41dfffffffc00000  d11 c3e0000000000000
07-25 16:23:52.467: INFO/DEBUG(64):  d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
07-25 16:23:52.467: INFO/DEBUG(64):  d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
07-25 16:23:52.467: INFO/DEBUG(64):  d16 000000c240035428  d17 c037000000000000
07-25 16:23:52.467: INFO/DEBUG(64):  d18 4044800000000000  d19 0000000000000000
07-25 16:23:52.467: INFO/DEBUG(64):  d20 3ff0000000000000  d21 8000000000000000
07-25 16:23:52.467: INFO/DEBUG(64):  d22 c044800000000000  d23 0000000000000000
07-25 16:23:52.467: INFO/DEBUG(64):  d24 0000000000000000  d25 0000000000000000
07-25 16:23:52.467: INFO/DEBUG(64):  d26 0100010001000100  d27 0100010001000100
07-25 16:23:52.467: INFO/DEBUG(64):  d28 0100010001000100  d29 3ff0000000000000
07-25 16:23:52.467: INFO/DEBUG(64):  d30 0000000000000000  d31 3ff0000000000000
07-25 16:23:52.467: INFO/DEBUG(64):  scr 60000012
07-25 16:23:52.517: INFO/DEBUG(64):          #00  pc 00011cf0  /system/lib/libc.so
07-25 16:23:52.517: INFO/DEBUG(64):          #01  pc 0000be62  /system/lib/libc.so
07-25 16:23:52.517: INFO/DEBUG(64):          #02  pc 0000cdc2  /system/lib/libc.so
07-25 16:23:52.517: INFO/DEBUG(64):          #03  pc 0006b372  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
07-25 16:23:52.517: INFO/DEBUG(64):          #04  pc 0005d7d0  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
07-25 16:23:52.517: INFO/DEBUG(64):          #05  pc 00017034  /system/lib/libdvm.so
07-25 16:23:52.517: INFO/DEBUG(64):          #06  pc 0004572c  /system/lib/libdvm.so
07-25 16:23:52.517: INFO/DEBUG(64):          #07  pc 000293ec  /system/lib/libdvm.so
07-25 16:23:52.517: INFO/DEBUG(64): code around pc:
07-25 16:23:52.517: INFO/DEBUG(64): afd11cd0 2d00682d e029d1fb b12b68db c05cf8df 
07-25 16:23:52.517: INFO/DEBUG(64): afd11ce0 f8442001 4798000c e054f8df 26002227 
07-25 16:23:52.517: INFO/DEBUG(64): afd11cf0 2000f88e eee4f7fb f7fd2106 f04fe802 
07-25 16:23:52.517: INFO/DEBUG(64): afd11d00 91035180 460aa901 96012006 f7fc9602 
07-25 16:23:52.517: INFO/DEBUG(64): afd11d10 a905eb88 20024632 eb92f7fc eed0f7fb 
07-25 16:23:52.517: INFO/DEBUG(64): code around lr:
07-25 16:23:52.517: INFO/DEBUG(64): deadba8c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff 
07-25 16:23:52.517: INFO/DEBUG(64): deadba9c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff 
07-25 16:23:52.517: INFO/DEBUG(64): deadbaac ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff 
07-25 16:23:52.517: INFO/DEBUG(64): deadbabc ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff 
07-25 16:23:52.517: INFO/DEBUG(64): deadbacc ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff 
07-25 16:23:52.517: INFO/DEBUG(64): stack:
07-25 16:23:52.517: INFO/DEBUG(64):     484ffa48  000000b4  
07-25 16:23:52.517: INFO/DEBUG(64):     484ffa4c  afd146c9  /system/lib/libc.so
07-25 16:23:52.517: INFO/DEBUG(64):     484ffa50  afd425a0  /system/lib/libc.so
07-25 16:23:52.517: INFO/DEBUG(64):     484ffa54  afd4254c  /system/lib/libc.so
07-25 16:23:52.517: INFO/DEBUG(64):     484ffa58  00000000  
07-25 16:23:52.517: INFO/DEBUG(64):     484ffa5c  afd156e3  /system/lib/libc.so
07-25 16:23:52.517: INFO/DEBUG(64):     484ffa60  afd14699  /system/lib/libc.so
07-25 16:23:52.517: INFO/DEBUG(64):     484ffa64  afd14699  /system/lib/libc.so
07-25 16:23:52.517: INFO/DEBUG(64):     484ffa68  00000074  
07-25 16:23:52.517: INFO/DEBUG(64):     484ffa6c  afd42328  /system/lib/libc.so
07-25 16:23:52.517: INFO/DEBUG(64):     484ffa70  00000000  
07-25 16:23:52.517: INFO/DEBUG(64):     484ffa74  484ffa9c  
07-25 16:23:52.517: INFO/DEBUG(64):     484ffa78  0000a000  [heap]
07-25 16:23:52.517: INFO/DEBUG(64):     484ffa7c  afd1493b  /system/lib/libc.so
07-25 16:23:52.517: INFO/DEBUG(64):     484ffa80  df002777  
07-25 16:23:52.517: INFO/DEBUG(64):     484ffa84  e3a070ad  
07-25 16:23:52.517: INFO/DEBUG(64): #00 484ffa88  afd438e4  /system/lib/libc.so
07-25 16:23:52.517: INFO/DEBUG(64):     484ffa8c  afd1040c  /system/lib/libc.so
07-25 16:23:52.517: INFO/DEBUG(64):     484ffa90  afd42328  /system/lib/libc.so
07-25 16:23:52.517: INFO/DEBUG(64):     484ffa94  484ffae4  
07-25 16:23:52.517: INFO/DEBUG(64):     484ffa98  003b63b0  [heap]
07-25 16:23:52.517: INFO/DEBUG(64):     484ffa9c  fffffbdf  
07-25 16:23:52.527: INFO/DEBUG(64):     484ffaa0  afd42328  /system/lib/libc.so
07-25 16:23:52.527: INFO/DEBUG(64):     484ffaa4  afd4372c  /system/lib/libc.so
07-25 16:23:52.527: INFO/DEBUG(64):     484ffaa8  003b63b0  [heap]
07-25 16:23:52.527: INFO/DEBUG(64):     484ffaac  afd0be67  /system/lib/libc.so
07-25 16:23:52.527: INFO/DEBUG(64): #01 484ffab0  432a4e40  
07-25 16:23:52.527: INFO/DEBUG(64):     484ffab4  ad36b2fd  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
07-25 16:23:52.527: INFO/DEBUG(64):     484ffab8  00001404  
07-25 16:23:52.527: INFO/DEBUG(64):     484ffabc  afd43760  /system/lib/libc.so
07-25 16:23:52.527: INFO/DEBUG(64):     484ffac0  00000010  
07-25 16:23:52.527: INFO/DEBUG(64):     484ffac4  003b63b0  [heap]
07-25 16:23:52.527: INFO/DEBUG(64):     484ffac8  484ffae4  
07-25 16:23:52.527: INFO/DEBUG(64):     484ffacc  432a4e34  
07-25 16:23:52.527: INFO/DEBUG(64):     484ffad0  432a4e40  
07-25 16:23:52.527: INFO/DEBUG(64):     484ffad4  afd0cdc5  /system/lib/libc.so
```

has anyone come across anything similar before, and what did you do to work around it?

Comment: If the answer was helpful for you - upvote plese. If it was the solution - upvote and accept it.

Comment: Mike - why dont you give any feedback?

Answer (score 0):

The same problem is discussed here: [Application crash with signal 11 (SIGSEGV)](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=16644)

As I understood it - it was a bug with the status **FutureRelease** as for 31 May 2011.

And the status of this bug was changed to **Released** as for 23 Jun 2013.