# INF file for HID device - setting name and icon

Tags: hid, inf, driver-signing

I'm looking to create an inf file for a HID device (which has a custom VID/PID). I just want to replace the strings "HID-compliant device" and "USB Input Device" for our device with our strings.

I know this will need signing by Microsoft, but is there a good example of how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Example of custom HID INF file on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/jj131716%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) may help you

Comment: draws on the two main resources google highlights, and good technically correct answers. Its a shame that nobody has done this in real life...

Comment: @MikeHudgell - thank you for your accept. Vote is also up please

Comment: @MikeHudgell - I have also answered your other [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6818474/sigsegv-when-writing-java-code) and upvoted it

Comment: @MikroDel Do not only provide a link as an answer. Your second link is now broken and has been deleted. What if the next one also gets deleted? Please edit your answer and provide a proper level of information in the body of your answer and use the link as a reference. Thank you.

Comment: @M-- its not my blog. The information can be updated. If you want to make this answer better and also have an idea and time. Why not? :)

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have the time, but you can consider including some information from the link you are referring to in the body of your answer for future. Cheers.